# Trying to identify a film about a small town that faces a yearly danger only one remembers

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to located a film which I remember watching with my dad in the early 90s, although the film might have been older. There is a small town which comes under threat once a year and must be saved by a chosen one. He is the only person who retains the memory of the night each year, the entire population of the town seem to forget come the morning.

This year, a teenager must take on the role of saving the town from an alien threat instead of his father who has previously protected the town. There might have been a scene in an abandoned warehouse and I believe the son tries to explain the situation to his female interest.

I've been searching for this film for quite a while now!

Comment: Take a look at this tried and tested [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details.

Comment: Sounds similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Giver_(film)

Comment: @Valorum - Are there aliens in The Giver?

Comment: @Adamant - Dunno. I've not seen it.

Comment: @Valorum - There aren’t. ;)